# I have a test env with bash 4 and loops work but the same loops do not run within the production env using bash 3

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, version

```
for i in `cat ip_list` ; do
    ping -c 1 $i 2&>1 > /dev/nul && echo $i good || echo $i bad ;
done
```

This loop works in bash 4 but not in bash 3... what should I change in the loop for the older RedHat 5 machines running version 3?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain in detail what you expect the code to do and what you are seeing instead.

Comment: You don't want to redirect to `/dev/nul` - you probably mean `/dev/null`.

Comment: When you say "it does not work with `bash` 3", what do you mean?  What happens?  Note that you've redirected errors to standard output, but only the original standard output goes to `/dev/null` (spell-corrected); the errors go to the original standard output.  To get both to go to `/dev/null`, you reverse the order of the redirections (they're processed left-to-right).

Answer (score 0):

Three problems,

1. /dev/nul should be /dev/null
2. 2&>1 should be 2>&1
3. some systems don't support -c option in command ping. Please confirm your command by manually run the command, if you get any error message.

   ping -c 1 IP_ADDRESS

If you successfully run the `ping -c` command, then the code can be replaced by

```
for i in `cat ip_list` ; do
    ping -c 1 $i 2>&1 > /dev/null &&  echo $i good || echo $i bad ;
done
```

Comment: Why i can't put the line "ping -c 1 IP_ADDRESS" in {} ? Is the bug in Stackoverfolow?